# How to resume Activity instead of starting its duplicate

Tags: android, navigation

I am starting `PlayActivity` by `playButton` in the way listed below. The problem is when I go back to the main menu and click the playButton again I am creating another intent instead of resuming old(I get Signal 11). Is there a way instead of using intent to get to the another activity?

```
 playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);          
                }

            });
```

Comment: Have you heard of Singletone Instance ? Just implement it. It will always make sure to run only one instance of your activity.

Comment: What do you mean by go back to the main menu? by backpress?

Comment: When you press back Activity gets removed from ActivityStack, so there is no need to look resuming the Activity. You have to call new instance each time..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. check the activity back stack. when you click back button activity is popped from the stack destroyed and previous activity in the stack takes focus

Comment: Going back to the main menu doesn't have to be through the back button. Maybe he's using a Menu button from his `PlayActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Manifest where PlayActivity is defined, add  `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

Comment: singleTop will only reuse the instance when it is already on top of the stack, source:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score 1):

set the appropriate flags for your intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```